# Proof of norm product in Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Prove that, in a Hilbert space,
$$
\Vert A+B\rVert \lVert A-B\rVert \le \lVert A\rVert^2 + \lVert B\rVert^2
$$

I was asked to do it without using the Cauchy inequality

I don't know which property to use, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is it a Hilbert space or just a Banach space.

Comment: A Hilbert space

Comment: Mention that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious inequality $0 \le (\|A+B\| - \|A - B\|)^2$ can be rewritten as
$$
2 \|A+B\|  \, \|A - B\| \le \|A+B\|^2 + \|A - B\|^2.
$$
By the Parallelogram Equality, the right side of the inequality above is equal to $2( \|A\|^2 + \|B\|^2)$. Now divide both sides by $2$ to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$\newcommand\sp[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}$
\begin{align}
(\Vert A+B\rVert \lVert A-B\rVert)^2
&=\sp{A+B}{A+B}\sp{A-B}{A-B}\\
&=(\sp{A}{A}+\sp{A}{B}+\sp{B}{A}+\sp{B}{B})\\
&\qquad\cdot(\sp{A}{A}-\sp{A}{B}-\sp{B}{A}+\sp{B}{B})\\
&=(\sp{A}{A}+\sp{B}{B})^2-(\sp{A}{B}+\sp{B}{A})^2\\
&=(\lVert A\rVert^2+\lVert B\rVert^2)^2-(\sp{A}{B}+\sp{B}{A})^2
\end{align}
What can you say about $(\sp{A}{B}+\sp{B}{A})^2$?

Comment: that it is equal or greater than zero? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @mandis1i Yes, $\langle A,B\rangle+\langle B,A\rangle$ is real (also if the Hilbert space is over the complex numbers), so its square is nonnegative.

Answer (score 0):

$||A+B||||A-B||=\sqrt{(A+B,A+B)(A-B,A-B)}=\sqrt{(||A||^2+||B||^2+(A,B)+(B,A))(||A||^2+||B||^2-(A,B)-(B,A))}=\sqrt{(||A||^2+||B||^2)^2-((A,B)+(B,A))^2}.$
 $((A,B)+(B,A))^2\geq 0$ we have $||A+B||||A-B||\leq ||A||^2+||B||^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful!